# How to exclude printing all the hidden links from a website using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following code prints all the links from the website which includes some hidden links as well. These hidden links are displayed as blank on the console. How do I write my code in a such a way that it only prints visible link from the website and not print hidden links in the form of blanks.

```
driver.get("https://www.duke-energy.com/my-account/sign-in");

List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

System.out.println("The total number of links on the page are :"+link.size());

for(int i=0;i<link.size();i++)
{
    String url=link.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stream and `filter` to filter for visible links using `isDisplayed`:

```
driver.get("https://www.duke-energy.com/my-account/sign-in");

List<WebElement> links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("a")));
System.out.println("The total number of links on the page are :" + links.size());

List<WebElement> vlinks = links.stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("The total number of visible links on the page are :" + vlinks.size());

for (WebElement link : vlinks) {
    String url = link.getText();
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Visible links and text not empty:

```
links.stream().filter(e -> e.isDisplayed() && !e.getText().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText()));
```

Comment: I believe the link is not hidden rather just empyty links. If it was hidden it would not be found anyways.

Comment: @pdrersin Selenium can find hidden links, it just throws if you try to interact with them.